# Get ORM Column name in a controller

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, annotations, metadata

```
 /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="anio_detalle", type="integer")
     */
    private $detalle;
```

Is there any way to get the column name **"anio_detalle"** from a controller.

I know i can get a table name by using

```
$em->getClassMetadata('StoreBundle:User')->getTableName();
```

But is there any way to get the column name?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html#usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$em->getClassMetadata('Acme\MyEntity')->getFieldName('detalle');
```